# Issue with training tesseract 4.0

Tags: tesseract, training-data

Now I want to train `tesseract` for arabic language with specific font exactly the digits
According to [`tesseract docs`](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/TrainingTesseract-4.00#creating-starter-traineddata) 
You must create data first and I have this now

#### Training

This command to create the training data and eval lists

```
$TRAINING/tesstrain.sh --fonts_dir $FOLDER/simplified-arabic --lang ara --linedata_only \
  --noextract_font_properties --langdata_dir $FOLDER \
  --tessdata_dir $FOLDER/arabox/tessdata \
  --fontlist "Simplified Arabic Bold" --output_dir $FOLDER/araeval
```

#### Output

This is the output

```
        === Starting training for language 'ara'
[ر أبر 25 22:17:23 EET 2018] /usr/local/bin/text2image --fonts_dir=/home/amir-paymob/WorkSpace/learnopencv/simplified-arabic --font=Simplified Arabic Bold --outputbase=/tmp/font_tmp.sUvtJ9ehJT/sample_text.txt --text=/tmp/font_tmp.sUvtJ9ehJT/sample_text.txt --fontconfig_tmpdir=/tmp/font_tmp.sUvtJ9ehJT
Rendered page 0 to file /tmp/font_tmp.sUvtJ9ehJT/sample_text.txt.tif

=== Phase I: Generating training images ===
Rendering using Simplified Arabic Bold
[ر أبر 25 22:17:24 EET 2018] /usr/local/bin/text2image --fontconfig_tmpdir=/tmp/font_tmp.sUvtJ9ehJT --fonts_dir=/home/amir-paymob/WorkSpace/learnopencv/simplified-arabic --strip_unrenderable_words --leading=32 --char_spacing=0.0 --exposure=0 --outputbase=/tmp/tmp.bBjBa5bzUW/ara/ara.Simplified_Arabic_Bold.exp0 --max_pages=3 --font=Simplified Arabic Bold --text=/home/amir-paymob/WorkSpace/learnopencv/ara/ara.training_text
Rendered page 0 to file /tmp/tmp.bBjBa5bzUW/ara/ara.Simplified_Arabic_Bold.exp0.tif

=== Phase UP: Generating unicharset and unichar properties files ===
[ر أبر 25 22:17:25 EET 2018] /usr/local/bin/unicharset_extractor --output_unicharset /tmp/tmp.bBjBa5bzUW/ara/ara.unicharset --norm_mode 2 /tmp/tmp.bBjBa5bzUW/ara/ara.Simplified_Arabic_Bold.exp0.box
Extracting unicharset from box file /tmp/tmp.bBjBa5bzUW/ara/ara.Simplified_Arabic_Bold.exp0.box
Wrote unicharset file /tmp/tmp.bBjBa5bzUW/ara/ara.unicharset
[ر أبر 25 22:17:25 EET 2018] /usr/local/bin/set_unicharset_properties -U /tmp/tmp.bBjBa5bzUW/ara/ara.unicharset -O /tmp/tmp.bBjBa5bzUW/ara/ara.unicharset -X /tmp/tmp.bBjBa5bzUW/ara/ara.xheights --script_dir=/home/amir-paymob/WorkSpace/learnopencv
Loaded unicharset of size 13 from file /tmp/tmp.bBjBa5bzUW/ara/ara.unicharset
Setting unichar properties
Setting script properties
Writing unicharset to file /tmp/tmp.bBjBa5bzUW/ara/ara.unicharset

=== Phase E: Generating lstmf files ===
Using TESSDATA_PREFIX=/home/amir-paymob/WorkSpace/learnopencv/facerec/tessdata
[ر أبر 25 22:17:25 EET 2018] /usr/local/bin/tesseract /tmp/tmp.bBjBa5bzUW/ara/ara.Simplified_Arabic_Bold.exp0.tif /tmp/tmp.bBjBa5bzUW/ara/ara.Simplified_Arabic_Bold.exp0 lstm.train /home/amir-paymob/WorkSpace/learnopencv/ara/ara.config
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v4.0.0-beta.1-69-g10f4 with Leptonica
Page 1

=== Constructing LSTM training data ===
[ر أبر 25 22:17:25 EET 2018] /usr/local/bin/combine_lang_model --input_unicharset /tmp/tmp.bBjBa5bzUW/ara/ara.unicharset --script_dir /home/amir-paymob/WorkSpace/learnopencv --words /home/amir-paymob/WorkSpace/learnopencv/ara/ara.wordlist --numbers /home/amir-paymob/WorkSpace/learnopencv/ara/ara.numbers --puncs /home/amir-paymob/WorkSpace/learnopencv/ara/ara.punc --output_dir /home/amir-paymob/WorkSpace/learnopencv/araeval --lang ara --pass_through_recoder --lang_is_rtl
Loaded unicharset of size 13 from file /tmp/tmp.bBjBa5bzUW/ara/ara.unicharset
Setting unichar properties
Setting script properties
Config file is optional, continuing...
Reducing Trie to SquishedDawg
Error during conversion of wordlists to DAWGs!!
Moving /tmp/tmp.bBjBa5bzUW/ara/ara.Simplified_Arabic_Bold.exp0.lstmf to /home/amir-paymob/WorkSpace/learnopencv/araeval

Completed training for language 'ara'
```

### The problem

```
Error during conversion of wordlists to DAWGs!!
```

> I didn't understand what is that?

In the training itself using the lstm file

```
$TRAINING/lstmtraining --debug_interval 0 --max_iterations 1 \
--traineddata $FOLDER/arabox/tessdata/ara.traineddata \
  --net_spec '[1,36,0,1 Ct3,3,16 Mp3,3 Lfys48 Lfx96 Lrx96 Lfx256 O1c111]' \
  --model_output $OUTPUT/base --learning_rate 20e-4 \
  --train_listfile $FOLDER/araeval/ara.training_files.txt \
  --max_iterations 5000 &>$OUTPUT/basetrain.log
```

it enters in encoding infinite loop, `can't encode the character`

#### NOW

According to documentation

> Bold elements must be provided. Others are optional, but if any of the dawgs are provided, the punctuation dawg must also be provided. A new tool: `combine_lang_data` is provided to make a starter `traineddata` from a `unicharset` and optional wordlists.

but what is the `combine_lang_data`

Comment: can you see if the file really exist in `/tmp/`?`

`ls -l /tmp/tmp.3UiQNSIBLh/ara/ara.Simplified_Arabic_Bold.exp0.lstmf`

also check if /tmp/ could be running out of space?
    `df -h`

Comment: Sorry I edited the question to fit the problem now, can u check what is `Error during conversion of wordlists to DAWGs!!`

Comment: I don't have a good answer for you on this... might want to take a look at this: [https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/1147]

I would suggest you try the same thing with stable release 3.05.01 or the 4.0 version on master github...